# Stack divs in columns

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup which I can't change. I can only add `<div>`s to the wrapping container.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box" id="box1">1</div>
   <div class="box" id="box2">2</div>
   <div class="box" id="box3">3</div>
   <div class="box" id="box4">4</div>
   <div class="box" id="box5">5</div>
   <div class="box" id="box6">6</div>
</div>
```

It is possible to stack `<div>`s like in the following picture?

```
+------+--------+--------+
|   1  |    3   |    5   |
+------+--------+--------+
|      |        |        |
|   2  |    4   |    6   |
|      |        |        |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you not change ANY of the markup?  If that is the case, no.  If you can change everything inside the outer container then it is doable.

Answer (score 3):

### Individual positioning

If you need to create this layout only for this six columns than you could just position them individually, because you have `id`'s you could just position all `<div>`'s with the `#` id selector.

### Non expandable solution [[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Cz8/)]

This solution will work for your six column layout, but if you want to expand it and add more columns, then you need to add extra code to your CSS, like `.box:nth-child(8) {left: 150px;}`.

```
.container {
   position: relative;
}
.box {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
}
.box:nth-child(2n) {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {left: 0px;}
.box:nth-child(4) {left: 50px;}
.box:nth-child(6) {left: 100px;}
```

#### Improvement for flexibility [[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hy2BY/)]

As [Itay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947677/itay) mentioned, this solution can be improved if you use the `transform` property, so you could modify the CSS with this:

```
.box:nth-child(4) {transform: translate(100%);}
.box:nth-child(6) {transform: translate(200%);}
```

You still need to change the `top` property manually. Also don't forget to use vendor prefixes like `-webkit-` or `-ms-` if you need them.

### Expandable solution [[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qT9Ap/1/)]

This solution also uses the CSS3 `nth-child(n)` selector, but here we use relative positioning and a trick with the `margin-left` property. The source code of this solution is much compact/readable and it is expandable so you don't have to add more CSS selectors if you add more `box`es to your `container`, just simply add a new line to your HTML and it will work as a charm.

```
.box {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}
.box:nth-child(2n) {
   top: 50px;
   margin-left: -50px;
}
```

#### Improvement for flexibility [[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub4D2/)]

Don't forget that you can improve this solution too with the `transform` property:

```
.box:nth-child(2n) {
   transform: translate(0, 100%);
   margin-left: -50px;
}
```

However you still need to set the `margin-left` property by hand. If you do not find a dynamic way to change it by CSS you can use JavaScript/jQuery.

### CSS3 columns

CSS3 have this as a new feature, so you can easily create custom columns. Look at [this article](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-use-css3-columns/) for more, and also take a look at [Itay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19070533/).

Comment: @Itay Sorry, I wasn't aware of the numbering but now it works!

Comment: Now it's not really flexible because of the fixed sizes. Using `transforms` may make it a bit more flexible http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/a9Cz8/1/

Comment: @Itay He didn't mentioned that he need a flexible solution. However you clearly improved the solution.

Comment: See my answer for a completely flexible solution using `translate`

Answer (score 2):

## Alternative #1 - CSS columns

The simplest solution is using [CSS3 columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/sDUQW/)

```
.container { 
   -webkit-columns: 3;
      -moz-columns: 3;
           columns: 3;
}
```

- P.S - CSS3 columns hold some [browser support issues](http://caniuse.com/#search=column).

---

## Alternative #2 - CSS transforms

Using [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is still very flexible but [supports more browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) than CSS columns.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/TfUe8/)

```
.box:nth-child(n+2) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.box:nth-child(2n) {
    top: 100%;
}
.box:nth-child(3), .box:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
}
.box:nth-child(5), .box:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(200%);
            transform: translateX(200%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, try to wrap box1 and box2 to one div, then do the same for box3 and box4 and same for box5 and box6 a then set float left to those wrapping divs, something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="float:left">
    <div class="box" id="box1">1</div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">2</div>
  <div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <div class="box" id="box3">3</div>
    <div class="box" id="box4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <div class="box" id="box5">5</div>
    <div class="box" id="box6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: op mentioned "I have the following markup wich i cannot change. "

Comment: He also mentioned this "I can only add divs to the wrapping container." So I interpreted it that he can add divs into container div and that is what I did

Comment: The problem is that the html is generated by the vaadin framework. An i cannot control it. I cannot add markup, but the framework generate A LOT of divs wrapping the elements wich i can add classes for styling.